# Convert For loop into LINQ caused errors

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert the following for-loop code into LINQ to improve readability. The for loop works fine. However, LINQ gave me errors and can anyone point me out where I made mistake?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= dataset.Count(); i++)
{
            string source = dataset.First(e => e.ID == i).SourceMachine.Trim();
            string target = dataset.First(e => e.ID == i).TargetMachine.Trim();
            int count = dataset.First(e => e.ID == i).Connection;
            GraphEdge edge = new GraphEdge(source, target, count);
            edgeList.Add(edge);
}
```

MY wrong LINQ is like:

```
var edges = dataset.Select(e => new GraphEdge
    {
        Source = e.SourceMachine.Trim(),
        Target = e.TargetMachine.Trim(),
        Weight = e.Connection
    }).ToList();
```

FYI:

```
IQueryable<SeedTest> dataset = builder.GetAllSeedTest();


 public partial class SeedTest
  {
    public string SourceMachine { get; set; }
    public string TargetMachine { get; set; }
    public int Connection { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
  }
```

Update GraphEdge class

```
public class GraphEdge : IEdge<string>
    {
        public GraphEdge(string s, string t, int w)
        {
            Source = s;
            Target = t;
            Weight = w;
        }

        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string Target { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Linq is a `foreach` replaement, not a `for` replacement, are you aware of the differences?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain there should be some performance difference for sure. Another one is about accessing the index. I just want to see how the syntax looks like if I used LINQ to add new object to the edge list.

Comment: The only significant difference that jumps out at me is the LINQ result may be in a different order, assuming of course that the 3 parameters to GraphEdge class are Source, Target, and Weight and setting the properties will have the same effect.  Otherwise, just call `new GraphEdge(SourceMachine.Trim(),e.TargetMachine.Trim(),e.Connection)` in your Select.

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not seem advantageous to use linq here but still if you want you can try:

```
var edges = dataset.Select(t =>
            {
                var obj = dataset.First(m => dataset.IndexOf(t).Equals(t.ID));
                return new GraphEdge(obj.SourceMachine.Trim(), obj.TargetMachine.Trim(), obj.Connection);
            }).ToArray();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not Linq.  You are intializing variable in a class Try something like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GraphEdge graphEdge = new GraphEdge();
            var edges = graphEdge.dataset.Select(e => new GraphEdge()
            {
                Source = e.SourceMachine.Trim(),
                Target = e.TargetMachine.Trim(),
                Weight = e.Connection
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class GraphEdge
    {

        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string Target { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }

        public IQueryable<SeedTest> dataset = builder.GetAllSeedTest();

        public GraphEdge()
        {
        }
        public GraphEdge(string s, string t, int w)
        {
            Source = s;
            Target = t;
            Weight = w;
        }

        public partial class SeedTest
        {
        public string SourceMachine { get; set; }
        public string TargetMachine { get; set; }
        public int Connection { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        }

    }
}​
```

Comment: I didn't see any difference between your solution and my code snippet. Neither works.

Comment: There are lots of differences.  At least mine doesn't give compiler errors.  It appears that GraphEdge is a class and you posted code didn't show that.  I did the best I could creating missing object in you code.  The most significant error was the way you called the GraphEdge constructor..  Source, Targe, and Weight weren't defined and made them public with {get; set;} to give them visibility.

Answer (score 0):

GraphEdge doesn't have a default constructor (one with no parameters). I suspect this would work just fine:

```
var edges = dataset.Select(e => new GraphEdge(
        e.SourceMachine.Trim(),
        e.TargetMachine.Trim(),
        e.Connection)).ToList();
```